# OpenGL 3+ not activating

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics, opengl

I'm on an Ubuntu 16.0.4 machine with an AMD radeon HD 3650 card. According to https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Grafikkarten/AMD/radeon/ this card does support OpenGL 3.3 since 14.04 but when i run glxinfo it quotes "OpenGL version String : 2.1"
Of course i tried to install the radeon driver, by running the command, which gives me the info, that this package is already installed and on the latest version. 
 
The `glxinfo | grep Open` gives this

```
Vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center (0x8086)
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset 
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 17.1.0-devel
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 2.0 Mesa 17.1.0-devel
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0.16
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

So why am I asking? I programmed a game using java and lwjgl, but i did this on a mac with opengl 4something installed. The game requires openGL 3.3. i recently added a linux mashine to my workflow and compiling the code gives me an glfw_version_unavailable which (should) come from my graphicscard still using openGL 2.1

so my question is: how do i configure ... the radeo driver (?) ...correctly to use openGL 3.3 instead of version 2.1?

thanks in advance

Comment: I'd be really surprised if radeon HD 3650 had Opengl 3.3 support with radeon driver. It does in Windows, and it might have had it in 14.04 with the proprietary AMD driver (fglrx), but I doubt it applies to radeon in 16.04. Can you actually add the output of `glxinfo | grep Open` to the question.

Comment: I suggest installing 14.04 with `fglrx`. I think it is the only way.

Comment: @mikewhatever hm, thats pretty lame. but i looked up the amd-driver site and it seems that you are correct. looks like there is no "correct" combination of the old card and the new OS. I will add the glxinfo. Thanks alot

Comment: @Pilot6 after what i told to mikewhatever that kinda makes sense...thanks, i will try it.

Comment: ok, i did the downgrad but without success. still using the old version 2.1...which makes sence, according to this https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Grafikkarten/AMD/fglrx/ my card is not even supported on 14.04 but only 12.04 (i should have checked that sooner) I guess it is time for a new graphics card.  Thanks a lot guys, i think this is closed ^^